# Call UserPasswordEncoderInterface encodePassword in DoctrineMigrations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-migrations

I am trying to encode a password with the encodePassword function from `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;` inside my migration here is my code
I tried with `implements UserPasswordEncoderInterface` but i did not manage to use this method encodePassword

The error is

> Call to a member function encodePassword() on null

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace DoctrineMigrations;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
use App\Entity\User;


/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
final class Version20201112164728 extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * @var UserPasswordEncoderInterface
     */
    private $encoder;


    public function getPassword($password)
    {
        $user = new User();
        return $this->encoder->encodePassword($user,$password);
    }


    public function getDescription(): string
    {
        return '';
    }


    public function up(Schema $schema): void
    {
       
    }

    public function postUp(Schema $schema): void
    {
        $this->connection->insert('users', [
            'id'         => Uuid::uuid4(),
            'email'      => 'xxx@xxx.com',
            'password'   => $this->getPassword('foo'),
   
        ]);
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema): void
    {


    }

}
```

Comment: `private $encoder;` is null. So you call a function on a non-defined variable (at `$this->encoder->encodePassword(...);`). This also tells you the error message.

Comment: I see , so how could i call the method encodePassword from my final class inside my postUp method ?

Comment: You are missing injecting encoder. Your class does not have a constructor. Read on dependency injection and autowiring on symfony.

Comment: Básically `__construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)` (and initialize the property).

Comment: Migration classes are not autowired.  Take a look [here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.1/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#migration-dependencies) for an example of injecting an external service.  It takes some effort as it involves creating a new migration factory and all kinds of good stuff.  Take it step by step.

Comment: I am a bit curious as to why you are doing this as part of a migration as opposed to use [fixtures](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-encoding-passwords).  It's not that you can't but it seems a bit unusual.

Comment: @Cerad well i can't use fixtures in production i use the alice fixtures bundle. Fixtures command from console are only working in dev

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess if your migration needs to make a new table and seed it then it's a valid requirement.

Comment: In my case some fixture creation cannot be called just via running `doctrine:fixtures:load` since in the context of Kubernetes the app needs to be aware if the command has been already run or not (there's no guaranteed that the app will run on just a single container). Hence I'm using migrations to run those initialization commands and be sure that they get executed just once. – It gives a weird feel, I am not sure it is a good practice; but I couldn't find a better solution in the context of multi-container applications. Also, fixture are something I see just for development environment.

Comment: @Kamafeather , in production fixtures:load are disabled,  that is why i did not used it :(
I ended up by adding some    $this->connection->insert with the encoded password directly , since this was just to init my app with a user on the first run

Comment: Yes, that's what I said too: no fixtures on production . Yours is similar to my use case (just a different dependency to inject), about initialising the first user for the app, in the context of migrations; mine is specifically in the context of K8S (potentially multiple instances of the same app). Unfortunately atm Doctrine doesn't really allow having Migrations as services and one needs to write more code to wire everything correctly: no DI is available in the namespace, so one needs to define and register their own migration factory, as Cerad linked to you above.